# Reply address configuration Issue in bot-authentication-msgraph code

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I am using a Microsoft Graph api code to authenticate and get details of user.
I am trying to build and run below project.

[console csharp connect msgraph project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample)

After building and running the project , it redirects to a browser and ask to login using my account   and when i select my email account ,it shows the error (AADSTS500113 No reply address is registered for the application) in attached screenshot.

Please Help.
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: You mentioned "Bot authentication and user details from Azure Active Directory". For bot authentication this everything should be taken care of when you create a web app bot/bot channels registration. Are you really talking about bot authentication, or just user?

Answer (score -1):

Go to [apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

Click the "Edit Application Manifest" button.

Add `https://yourdomain.com/callback` to the replyUrls element.

## For Azure AD

If this does not fix your problem you might have to look at [Azure AD](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-aadsts500113-no-reply-address-is-registered-for-the-application-error/). I am not sure which solution you're looking for since your question was a bit decryptive formulated.

Comment: I am looking for Bot authentication and user details from Azure Active Directory . I have opened console-csharp-connect-sample.sln in Visual Studio.I have updated the correct github project link in the question. In Program.cs  
      var user = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
      string userId = user.Id;
      string mailAddress = user.UserPrincipalName;
     
      string displayName = user.DisplayName;                                   Code is failing in above line (Program.cs)

Comment: You should check the link i posted that will lead you to the source of your problem